# replace text in input file with hadoop MR

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a newbie on the MR and Hadoop front.
I wrote an MR for finding missing's in csv file and it is working fine. 
now I have an usecase where i need to parse a csv file and code it with the regarding category.

ex: "11,abc,xyz,51,61,78","11,adc,ryz,41,71,38",.............

now this has to be replaced as "1,abc,xyz,5,6,7","1,adc,ryz,4,7,3",.............

here i am doing a mod of 10 but there will be different cases of mod's.
data size is in gb's.

I want to know how to replace the content in-place for the input. Is this achievable with MR?

Basically i have not seen any file handling or writing based hadoop examples any where.

At this point i do not want to go to HBase or other db tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not replace data in place, since HDFS files are append only, and can not be edited. 
I think simplest way to achiece your goal is to register your data in the Hive as external table, and write your trnasformation in HQL. 
 
Hive is a system sitting aside of hadoop and translating your queries to MR Jobs. 
Its usage is not serious infrastructure decision as HBASE usage